# Python Pillow with Django .thumbnail() not respecting the sizes I declare

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to resize images with Pillow but it is not working correctly, I always get a very small image. I need three different sizes, that is why I'm doing this:

```
# Save Base64 Images
cover = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO((base64.b64decode(cover_image_64))))

cover_original = cover
cover_small = cover
cover_medium = cover

small_size = ProductCover.IMAGE_SIZES["small"]
medium_size = ProductCover.IMAGE_SIZES["medium"]

print(small_size)
print(medium_size)

# HERE-> 
cover_small.thumbnail(small_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
cover_medium.thumbnail(medium_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

original_image_file = StringIO.StringIO()
small_image_file = StringIO.StringIO()
medium_image_file = StringIO.StringIO()

cover_small.save(small_image_file, format="JPEG")
cover_medium.save(medium_image_file, format="JPEG")
cover_original.save(original_image_file, format="JPEG")

ProductCover.objects.create(product=product,
        original=InMemoryUploadedFile(original_image_file, None, "cover_original.jpg", 
        "image/jpeg", original_image_file.len, None),
        medium=InMemoryUploadedFile(medium_image_file, None, "cover_medium.jpg",
                                           "image/jpeg", medium_image_file.len, None),
        small=InMemoryUploadedFile(small_image_file, None, "small_small.jpg",
                                   "image/jpeg", small_image_file.len, None))
```

The print statements print this to the console:

```
(60, 60)
(512, 512)
```

Why then I get three 60*60 images?

The code seems so straightforward and simple that I'm completely lost. Maybe its Django. I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the same object reference to three variable names here:

```
cover_original = cover
cover_small = cover
cover_medium = cover
```

Since all three point to the same object, calling `.thumbnail()` on any of them will modify the others. Try cloning the image using [`Image.copy()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.copy) instead:

```
cover_original = cover.copy()
cover_small = cover.copy()
cover_medium = cover.copy()
```